# Idiomatic Kotlin way to find an element to the right of a pivot that's just greater than the pivot

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I would like to write a computer program such that given an array of numbers and a pivot index, it returns the index of the smallest element to the right of the pivot that is just greater than the pivot.

For example: if the input is `[1, 4, 7, 2, 5, 6]` and the pivot is at index `1` i.e. element `4`, then the output should be `4` which is the index of `5` because `5` is the smallest element to the right of `4` that is greater than `4`.

The following code works

```
fun justGreater(nums: IntArray, pivotIndex: Int): Int {
    var result = 0
    var currBest = Int.MAX_VALUE
    for (i in pivotIndex until nums.size) {
        if (nums[i] > nums[pivotIndex] && nums[i] < currBest) {
            result = i
            currBest = nums[i]
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I would like to write this idiomatically and succinctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following:

```
fun justGreater(nums: IntArray, pivotIndex: Int): Int {
    return nums.withIndex()
        .sortedBy { it.value }
        .first { it.index > pivotIndex && it.value > nums[pivotIndex] }
        .index
}
```

Another option:

```
fun justGreater(nums: IntArray, pivotIndex: Int): Int {
    return nums.mapIndexed { index, number -> index to number }
        .sortedBy { (_, number) -> number }
        .first { (index, i) -> index > pivotIndex && i > nums[pivotIndex] }
        .first // returns pair, so we need to get only index
}
```

One more option:

```
fun justGreater(nums: IntArray, pivotIndex: Int): Int {
    val filteredArr = nums.sliceArray(pivotIndex + 1 until nums.size)
        .filter { it > nums[pivotIndex] }
    return nums.indexOf(filteredArr.min() ?: -1) // we return -1 in case item was not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little improvement

```
fun IntArray.justGreater(pivotIndex: Int): Int {
    var result = 0
    var currBest = Int.MAX_VALUE
    for (i in pivotIndex until size) {
        if (get(i) > get(pivotIndex) && get(i) < currBest) {
            result = i
            currBest = get(i)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

I think there is no shortcut function to decrease code

Answer (score 0):

This returns the smallest closest value position to the right of pivot:

```
fun justGreater(nums: IntArray, pivotIndex: Int): Int {
    val least = nums.asList()
        .subList(pivotIndex + 1, nums.size)
        .filter { it > nums[pivotIndex] }
        .min()!!
    return nums.indexOf(least)
}
```